# Express route param regex repeats

Tags: node.js, regex, express

I have a route where `foo` param is supposed to be positive integer and restricted with regular expression and `*` star repeat:

```
app.get('/foo/:foo([1-9][0-9]*)', fooHandler);
```

It matches `/foo/10`,  but doesn't match `/foo/1` URL (route handler isn't called) and results in 404.

While

```
app.get('/foo/:foo([1-9])', fooHandler);
```

and

```
app.get('/foo/:foo([1-9][0-9]?)', fooHandler);
```

work, but they don't cover all param values.

Why does Express not match `[1-9][0-9]*` regex? How can it be fixed to match all positive integer `foo` values?

Comment: You can simply use `app.get('/foo/:foo([\d]*)', fooHandler);`.

Comment: @AmitSingh The objective is to not allow zero or leading zeroes.

Comment: Should route `'/foo/'` be a match ?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Real scenario is more complex than this one, but the point here is that I'd like to avoid req.param.foo validation in route handler and use route regexp to skip invalid param values.

Comment: Weird, http://forbeslindesay.github.io/express-route-tester/ with route `/foo/:foo([1-9][0-9]*)` match `/foo/1` which express version are you using ?

Comment: Nevermind, they use basic regex matching under the hood and not actual express route matching ...

Comment: @GabrielBleu Do they? I've checked this repo, and it seems that it uses  path-to-regexp  at some point. I'm at 4.15.3. I've just checked path-to-regexp version it's bundled with (0.1.x), and it results in `/^\/foo\/(?:([1-9][0-9](.*)))\/?$/i`... what the hell? And latest path-to-regexp parses it right.

Comment: I guess that that's because `*` has special meaning in routes, and updating path-to-regexp would break this. Still unclear if it can be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
app.get('/foo/:foo([1-9][0-9]{0,})', fooHandler);
```

instead of

```
app.get('/foo/:foo([1-9][0-9]*)', fooHandler);
```

I thougt if  `*` has a special meaning in routes , why complicate things ? Why not replace it with {0,} instead ? Btw, It works , I checked .